# How to enable ContainerInsights (setting) on an ECS cluster created from a Batch compute environment using Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have an AWS Batch compute environment defined in my Terraform files. The creation of the compute environment creates an ECS Cluster, where the containers are being run.

The issue I have with Terraform, is that while the `aws_batch_compute_environment` resource is managed by Terraform, then the `aws_ecs_cluster` which is created from it is not.

I want to enable ContainerInsights on this cluster, but because it is not managed I am struggling to understand how to do it.

This is how my Batch compute environment is currently defined:

```
resource "aws_batch_compute_environment" "fargate-batch-compute" {
  compute_environment_name = "fargate-batch-compute"

  compute_resources {
    max_vcpus          = 100
    security_group_ids = [...]
    subnets            = [...]
    type               = "FARGATE"
  }

  type = "MANAGED"
}
```

This is how to easily enable ContainerInsights on an ECS cluster using Terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "foo" {
  name = ""

  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}
```

**Notes:**

- I checked and it seems that it's not possible to pass an existing ECS cluster to the creation of the compute environment - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49983869/11808461)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to import the created resource in AWS to a new configured resource in your Terraform configuration.

If the newly created ECS Cluster is named `AWSBatch-foo-123456` than append to your Terraform configuration the following resource:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "foo-cluster" {
  name = "AWSBatch-foo-123456"
  
  setting {
    name  = "containerInsights"
    value = "enabled"
  }
}
```

and then execute `terraform import aws_ecs_cluster.foo-cluster AWSBatch-foo-123456`.

Now, the ECS cluster will be managed by Terraform and you can apply any setting on it.